# How to include embedded links in tweet with tweepy?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm trying to create a program that will download tweets from a user timeline as per `Client.get_users_tweets` method and look for external links inside those tweets.
From what I could gather, these objects reside into the `entities` field, but so far my query

```
author_id = 12345
Client.get_users_tweets(author_id, tweet_fields = ['entities'])
```

yelds the tweets with an empty entity attribute.

I'm probably missing something in the attachments field, but I can't figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

You gonna need the `tweepy.Client` class in Tweepy v4.x for that, first install `tweepy` `pip install tweepy==4.3.0`

Then you can use python like this for example:

```
import tweepy

API_KEY = "your_api_key"
API_SECRET = "your_api_secret"
BEARER_TOKEN = "your_bearer_token"

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=BEARER_TOKEN)

author_id = 12345
tweets = client.get_users_tweets(author_id, expansions=["attachments.media_keys"], tweet_fields=["entities"])

for tweet in tweets:
    if 'entities' in tweet and 'urls' in tweet.entities:
        for url in tweet.entities.urls:
            print(url.expanded_url)
```

Dont forget to replace `API_KEY`, `API_SECRET`, and `BEARER_TOKEN` with your own credential.

Comment: Not working. Error message: "The `expansions` query parameter value [entities.urls] is not one of [author_id,referenced_tweets.id,referenced_tweets.id.author_id,entities.mentions.username,attachments.poll_ids,attachments.media_keys,in_reply_to_user_id,geo.place_id,edit_history_tweet_ids]"